# Как защитить данные в приложении?

Tags: java, android, безопасность

Есть программа в которой есть возможность войти и написать свой отзыв.
Есть человек коорый подсмотрел ссылки и теперь шлет свои отзывы через свою программу.
Как можно защитить прогамму и не дать ему писать свои отзывы если мы знаем:

1. Любой код можно декомпилировать и подсмотреть строку.
2. Можно засниферить сссылки из Chаrles, к примеру.
3. Можно выдавать пользователям токен при логине, но какой в этом смысл если тот человек точно так же получит доступ к ссылке входа и будет получать этот токен в своей проге.
4. Можно сравнивать SHA1 подписи приложения, но какой в этом смысл если он узнает подпись апк и будет подставлять ее в строку.

Как решить этот вопрос, как не дать злоумышленнику доступ к своему API?

Comment: Добавляя вызов url из c++, вы ровным счетом ничего не поменяете. На том же роутере можно глянуть что куда и когда. Тут нужно идти другим путем - подтверждение отзыва, либо отзыв только авторизованным и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Всё в кучу -> разные огромные темы Аутентификация, Шифрование, Спам, РеверсИнжиниринг ....

Доступ к вашему АPI решается путем Аутентификации, регистрацией, как вы там сделаете безопасность в этапах регистрации это уже другой вопрос. Но это стандартная практика которая используется во многих API, не думаю что необходимо что-то новое придумывать.

Те ваш ответ это 3-й пункт, он получил токен и будет по нему ходить, ведь он прошел Регистрацию у вас, те он обычный пользователь вашей API и вы его **идентифицируете**, вот только если он потом может написать спам бота и рассылать отзывы, или как-то заDOSить вас, это уже брешь в самой API, Серваках и так далее, нужно смотреть.

Comment: Суть в чем:
Как спрятать от него ссылки, что бы он не видел куда отправляются данные, может быть добавить их в С++ код и запрашивать из java? Т.к. я смотрю оно не декомпилирует С++.
Как сделать так что бы человек не видел данные из URL, использовать https?

Comment: а в этом плане, ну здесь вы 100% не защититесь. Вы можете засолить вашу ссылку по которой вы ходите. Но... весь смысл теряется, когда у меня есть друг в поставщике услуг, ну интернет-провайдер как принято, ну и я смогу посмотреть. Поэтому я в ответ и написал, что вопрос очень общий, сложна дать ответ, даже непонятна цель которую вы приследуете. Если в native унести, это усложнит поиск, но для тех кто этим занимается - это классика. не составит особого труда отследить последовательность и вытянуть ссыль

Comment: чтоб Java плохо декомпилировалась, вам нужно обфускатор настроить, было несколько тем по этому поводу ProGuard в андройд занимается этим, есть сторонние либы которые хорошо работают, название не вспомню сейчас. Вроде даже в GoogleConsole появилсь апи по шифрованию, не пробовал, поэтому не буду врать, мб инетерсно посмотрите Да это огромная тема... я даже не знаю как помочь вам ))

Answer (score 0):

нельзя 100% защититься.
но можно усложнить жизнь, чтобы взлом не стоил конечной цели.
Чтобы обойти MiTM атаку можно сделать https + пининг сертификатов.